# Perform a operation in a datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Good afternoon everyone, I am new deceloping in C# more specific in WPF and I am trying to perform a sum between diferent columns from the following datagrid:
[image: datagrid] Then I want to sum for example the 3rd column with the 5th colum and put the result in the 8th column.

I create a button to perform this operation, but when I try to access to the dat I am not getting the correct information, My way to do it is the following:

```
 private void calcular_valores()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < AcumProp.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < AcumProp.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                TextBlock b = AcumProp.Columns[i].GetCellContent(AcumProp.Items[j]) as TextBlock;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(b);
            }
        }
    }
```

But I don't know why it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend changing the DataGrid.ItemsSource in the Model layer. Just make sure that the ItemsSource implements NotifyPropertyChanged. For example:

```
public ObservableCollection<myItem> source { get; set; }
public void AddValues(int index)
{
    source[index].col8 = source[index].col3 + source[index].column5;
}
```